# How do i add multiple editors with the support array under a custom post type

Tags: php, html, wordpress

**update** I added a metabox using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box  Unfortunatly it only adds the metabox to the post and page types.  I have a custom post type called "custom-post-type.php" how would I link them?

The code:

```
  'supports' =>
     array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
```

http://vvcap.net/db/tckvzGhN_TtUvcsdTeo9.htp

I'm using the get_content(); where it says idea.

I will use custom fields for the skills (will be a list)

I'm using get_excerpt(); where it says process

*I still need a larger editor for **conclusion.***

Can I seperate custom fields between skills and ***contributions*** (will also be a list)
HTML code:

```
<section class="main">
      <div id="overview">
      <header> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?   >/library/images/abstract.png"  />
          <h1>conclusion</h1>
        </header>
        <p></p>
      </div>
</section>
```

Any help with how to tackle this would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function [wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor)

```
 wp_editor(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'contributions', true), 'contributions');
```

the code can be palced to the meta box that server your custom values.

Comment: the problem is I haven't created the metabox yet on the admin side.  I only have html code.  any advice?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box i did this however this only adds it to post and pages.  I need this metabox on my custom post type